# Rails: How to show a random image, then another random image with a rating close to previous image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I'm from a JS background and Rails confuses the hell out of me. I'm trying to have a random image show up. If the image has a score of 1200, I want the second random image to show up have a score of between 800-1600. I hooked up my image uploading with carrierwave and Amazon S3. Here's my model for the image:

```
  create_table "photos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "score"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "contest_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "image"
  end

  add_index "photos", ["contest_id"], name: "index_photos_on_contest_id", using: :btree
  add_index "photos", ["user_id"], name: "index_photos_on_user_id", using: :btree
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: what database are you using? the way you select a random association may depend on that.

Comment: I'm using postgresql.